# Airflow won't let me convert try_number macros to an integer

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

My issue is rather simple, but yet no real solution is really offered. The DAG I am trying to build will have a critical environment variable that might change depending on the number of retries that it goes through. For example, after 3 retries we will switch the value of the environment variable `"critical_value"` value mentioned in the code below.

So when I push the code below, I get the following broken DAG error:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/sync/dags/example_dag.py] invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{ task_instance.try_number }}'
```

This is an error we get when we try to convert a string to an int. In this case, at runtime `'{{ task_instance.try_number }}'` will take the appropriate value of the try number of the run. I have tried also removing the int() converter but then get an error of comparing an integer and a string.

Any help will be immensely appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
# Required DAG arguments
default_args = {
    'owner':airflow,
    "depend_on_past":False,
    'start_date':datetime(2021, 6, 4),

    "retries": 3
}

# Instantiate DAG
with DAG(
    example_dag,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=@once,
    ) as dag:
    
    # Run python script of loader job
    full_script_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
        name=example_task,
        task_id=example_task_id,
        namespace=Variable.get("kubernetes_namespace"),
        image=some_image,
        configmaps=CONFIG_MAPS,
        secrets=SECRETS,
        volumes=[logging_volume],
        volume_mounts=[logging_volume_mount],
        env_vars={
            "critical_value": "value_if_true" if int('{{ task_instance.try_number }}') >= 3 else "value_if_false"
        }
)
```

Comment: I don't know if you can use jinja templates in an `if` clause inside the parameter. Did you try just setting `env_vars={"critical_value": "{{ task_instance.try_number }}"}` to see if the value is properly received?

Comment: Hey @bruno-uy! Thanks for answer. That's an interesting point about not using the jinja in the condition. Will see if I can play more around with that. 

Also, confirming that value has been properly received.

Comment: Great @maurice-maurice! What you can do is to process the `try_number` inside the operator and instead of acting upon the `critical_value`, just use the `try_number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aiflow can handle the `if` expression and correct typing evaluation in Jinja but the whole value needs to be in the template syntax.  Try this (`env_vars` needs to be a `list` based on the documentation of the `KubernetesPodOperator` otherwise the value will be a stringified list):

```py
env_vars=[
            {
                "critical_value": "{{ 'value_if_true' if task_instance.try_number >= 3 else 'value_if_false' }}"
            }
        ],
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much. I knew it possibly could not be too complicated

Answer (score 0):

As we confirmed with your test, you cannot use jinja templated variables in an `if` clause inside the parameter. You tried this and the variable was read properly:

```py
env_vars={
    "critical_value": "{{ task_instance.try_number }}"
}
```

What you can do is to process the `try_number` inside the operator and instead of acting upon the `critical_value`, just use the `try_number`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Mind that I still have to branch out the possible values of `critical_value`, so I believe I will need an `if` condition somewhere.